# How to set the order of trees in ngx-graph?

Tags: angular, ngx-graph

How to set the order of trees using ngx-graph? I tried to play with the order of nodes/links in the arrays, but seems like the library has its own algorithm to place them into the view.

On the example below, I need to place them like(from top to bottom):

**1.** Big tree

**2.** '3' -> '4'

**3.** 'd1' -> 'd2'

Example:
[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-graph-demo-pm8i1t)